# Text file listings written to text file with comma delimited concatenated string

Tags: python, string, text, concatenation, csv

As a very new Python 3.7 user, I need to write a text file with one or a few words on each line - a list - to a text file with a single concatenated string, delimited by commas.

For instance, apples oranges bananas on separate lines, or two or three words each on a separate line, joined as one long string with commas showing where each line terminated.

I have used this code borrowed from this site, but it produced commas at the end of each word in a line:

```
with open('data.txt') as infile, open('dataout.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.read().replace(" ", ", "))
```

I am looking for something like the above, using the "with open" because of its more efficient "garbage collection" on longer lists, if I understand that explanation properly.  Then I can build upon my very limited knowledge for some parsing tasks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the final output you want it to look like

Comment: Wanmi, I would like a file like Able [new line] Baker [new line] Charlie [new line] to be rewritten to a new file as one line - Able, Baker, Charlie.

Comment: Or if the lines containe multiple phrases, it should look like: This is a good day [new line] And the sun is out [new line] Guess I shouldn't be wearing my raincoat > This is a good day, And the sun is out, Guess I shouldn't be wearing my raincoate [all in one comma delimited line]

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:
(1) replace line feeds with the desired commas;
(2) read the file as a list of lines, then `','.join(list_of_lines)`

Note that the second one can implement the list_of_lines as a list comprehension, using the `read` iterator.

Comment: OK Thank you; I will need to read up on how the "list" function works with this application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for

```
with open('data.txt') as infile, open('dataout.txt', 'w') as outfile:    
        lines = infile.read()
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(f"{line},")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open('data.txt') as infile, open('dataout.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.read().replace("\n", ", "))
```

Comment: Your two (2) lines of code were perfect.  My code was 9 lines plus spaces.  Brilliant - THAT is why I'm trying to learn Python.  Thank you!